# If the integral diverges while finding the expectation value

Tags: probability, density, calculus

I was wondering what the expectation value of a wave function might be if the corresponding integral diverges. For example, if I graph the probability density $\Psi (x) = \sqrt{\lambda/\pi} \exp(-\lambda(x-a)^2),$ I get [image: Probability Density]. So I expect that the expectation value $$<x> = a.$$

To obtain via algebra, I evaluate the expression $$<x> = \sqrt{\lambda/\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\exp(-\lambda(x-a)^2)dx}.$$

Using integration by parts on $$u = e^{2\lambda a x}, dv= x\exp{(-\lambda x^2)dx},$$ we have $$<x> = A\{-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp{(2\lambda a x)}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{-\frac{1}{2\lambda}2\lambda a\exp(2\lambda a x)dx}\},$$ with $$A=\sqrt{\lambda/\pi} \exp{(-\lambda a^2)}.$$This is reduced to
$$=A\{-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp{(2\lambda a x)}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{1}{2\lambda}\exp{(2\lambda a x)}|_{-\infty}^{\infty}\}.$$
However, both of these terms diverge to infinity. I was wondering why I would not get $a$ as the final answer.

Comment: Your integration by parts is wrong. The most simple way to see <x> = a is to change variable x = y + a and use equality $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty y e^{-\lambda y^2} dy = 0$.

Comment: Double check your integration by parts.  What happened to $v$?

Comment: You’re having a math issue, not a physics issue.